# Reading data from a textfile using the command line into an array in C confusion

Tags: c, arrays

I'm looking to read the following file into a 2D array using C.

```
AAAAAAAAAA
YYYYYYYYYY
AAAABAAAAA
XXXXXXXXXX
```

The files name is input4-10 and I'm using the following command line to run the program:

```
./a.out 4 10 <input4-10
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int N=0;
int M=0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Usage : pairwise numberOfSequences lengthOfSequences\n eg. pairwise 10000 50\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&M);

    char strings[N][M];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s\n",strings[i]);
    }

    printf("[] %s\n",strings[0]);
    printf("[] %s\n",strings[1]);
    printf("[] %s\n",strings[2]);
    printf("[] %s\n",strings[3]);
}
```

But when I print this out, I keep getting:

```
[] AAAAAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYAAAABAAAAAXXXXXXXXXX
[] YYYYYYYYYYAAAABAAAAAXXXXXXXXXX
[] AAAABAAAAAXXXXXXXXXX
[] XXXXXXXXXX
```

How is this even happening?? In the following line `scanf("%s\n",strings[i]);` what exactly is being put into strings[i]? The whole fine? I'm so confused I literally want to have:

Strings:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
YYYYYYYYYY
AAAABAAAAA
XXXXXXXXXX
```

As a 2D array i.e:

```
strings = [A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A]
          [Y][Y][Y][Y][Y][Y][Y][Y][Y][Y]
          [A][A][A][A][B][A][A][A][A][A]
          [X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X]
```

etc. Any help would really be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings do not allow for the 0 terminator. Try this:

```
char strings[N][M+1];
```

What is happening is that the 0 terminator overflows into the next string, which is then overwritten by the next string data, etc. So printing each string prints the higher array elements too as the only 0 terminator is after the end of the last string, possibly over `j` which is unused.

Having said that, your code is still dangerous as it does not check whether the user entered a string that is longer than he specified. You can protect against string entry being too long by creating a format spec restricting the input length on the fly (the * length specifier as used by `printf` did not work in my compiler). The first two % signs are to create a single text %, the third % is part of %d which uses your string length M. There are two \ chars so that the text "\n" goes verbatim in the string, not as a newline.

```
char spec[20];
sprintf (spec, "%%%ds\\n", M);   // create format spec as say "%10s\n"
//printf ("Spec %s\n", spec);      // print the spec just so you can see
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    scanf(spec, strings[i]);
```